# Co-ordinated delete Mysql query

Tags: mysql

Can someone provide a delete query to delete older records(older than 5 days)for the below mysql tables with its reference tables? (All reference tables records also need to deleted otherwise crashes my application)

https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/zipkin-storage/mysql/src/main/resources/mysql.sql

I have no clue to write a coordinated delete query (deleting multiple tables in same query)

Comment: You should look into `ON CASCADE DELETE`, which might greatly simplify your problem.  Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: Create foreign keys

Comment: I am using InnoDB. I can't change my create queries as it comes as a package (open source library) only I need to write delete query

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE t1,t2 FROM t1
        INNER JOIN
    t2 ON t2.ref = t1.id 
WHERE
    t1.id = 1;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks sumesh. Will try it out

Comment: the above query for the tables zipkin_spans, zipkin_annotations (from these tables [link](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/zipkin-storage/mysql/src/main/resources/mysql.sql)) are fine when we go deleting all records!
For deleting records after certain days like 

WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(zipkin_spans.start_ts/1000000) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
is not working. Please help @sumeshTG

Comment: how do i add additional where condition in delete stmt @sumesh-tg

Comment: Do the selection query first then go for DELETE

Comment: can you throw me a simple example with query

Comment: As per your table design start_ts is BIGINT am i right? So you need to convert this to date first then filter as you wish

Comment: select FROM_UNIXTIME(1376750476349/1000); use this to get timestamp

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will try

Comment: tried with below command 
DELETE zipkin_spans,zipkin_annotations
FROM zipkin_spans INNER JOIN zipkin_annotations ON zipkin_annotations.trace_id = zipkin_spans.trace_id AND zipkin_spans.trace_id IN ( SELECT zipkin_spans.trace_id from zipkin_spans
  WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(zipkin_spans.start_ts/1000000) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
  ) but throwing error like:
Table 'zipkin_spans' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: But both command (delete and select) works perfectly when executed independently)

Comment: your ans will be helpful @Sumesh-TG

Comment: why your table name and field are same use alias.

Comment: DELETE zs.zipkin_spans,zipkin_annotations FROM zipkin_spans zs INNER JOIN zipkin_annotations ON zipkin_annotations.trace_id = zipkin_spans.trace_id AND zipkin_spans.trace_id IN ( SELECT zipkin_spans.trace_id from zipkin_spans WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(zipkin_spans.start_ts/1000000) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) )